# Disqus comment form not displayed on self hosted Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I have followed all instructions on installing Disqus commenting system on my website but the old comment form is still visible.

My question is: is `<?php comment_form(); ?>` enough to display the comments or there needs to be something else on the single.php page.

What else should I be taking care?

I don't have any other commenting engine installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

OK I found it.
Instead of using the `<?php comment_form(); ?>` I had to use `<?php comments_template(); ?>`.
That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

install woody snippets on your site
insert a new php snippet:

```
comments_template(); ?>
```

go in widget select custom html and place the code:

```
<div id="disqus_thread">
[wbcr_php_snippet id="THE ID WHAT WOODY GAVE YOU"]
</div>
```

and place the widget where you want

obviously don't forget to enable comments site-wide