# Disqus not showing up - Getting default comment form

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, disqus

I installed disqus on my wordpress site.
Bt it is not showing up. It says it will replace default comment form.

I'm showing it like this:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

But, default comment form is getting loaded.

Am I missing something?

Note:  I am using custom theme. Do I need to do something in it?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334393/disqus-comment-form-not-displayed-on-self-hosted-wordpress-site) seems to be the same as yours and answer says to use this instead.

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Not sure if it works on `localhost` by the way.